# shortest vector in lattice with linearly dependent integer vectors as generators

Tags: integer-lattices

I have a lattice generated by $m$ *integer* vectors such that each generator lies in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $m > n$. This clearly implies that these vectors are linearly dependent.

For lattices generated by linearly independent vectors, Minkowski's theorem implies an upper bound on the shortest vector, say in $\ell^\infty$ norm.

Is there an upper bound when the generators are linearly dependent?

If it helps, $m = \binom{n+1}{k+2}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Of particular interest to me is the case when $k = O\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}{\log(n)}}\right)$.

Comment: One way you might be able to work this out is by using the [Hermite normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form#Lattice_calculations).